# Sql Server 2008 R2 Full-Text Search understand two words and better ranking

Tags: sql, full-text-search, sql-server-2008-r2

Hi I'm trying to understand Full-Text Search in MS Sql Server.

I got a simple search working

```
SELECT *
FROM Product
WHERE FREETEXT (*, 'stackoverflow' );
```

Even got some simple rank working.

```
SELECT
   *
FROM
    Product
    INNER JOIN FREETEXTTABLE ( Product , * , 'stackoverflow' ) ft ON ( Product.ProductNo = ft.[Key] )
ORDER BY
    ft.Rank DESC
```

*My First Question is*
How do I control the rank more. Ex. I want the **products**, **name** column to give a higher rank, than the **description** column if the search word is found there.
and is it possible to make it search for only part of a word. ex.

***overflow*** -> return **stackoverflow**

**stack** -> return **stackoverflow**

*My Second Question*
How do I make it possible to find the correct result when searching after **stack overflow** in two word.
Since I'm going to have alot of products where some users are going to spell it in two words, when it is correctly spelled in one word.
I got a dictonary installed for my Full Text Catalog, but it don't help with searchword in two words.

### Product Table

- Id
- Name
- Description

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the first part of your question: You'll need to use 2 queries with a union, providing a 'weight' of your own, something like this...

```
select  [key], sum(rnk) as weightRank
from
    (
    select Rank * 2.0 as rnk, [key] from freetexttable(tableName,Title,'free text string')
    union all
    select Rank * 1.0 as rnk, [key] from freetexttable(tableName,Description,'free text string')
    ) as t
group by [key]
```

Second part of your question:

```
SELECT *
FROM Product
WHERE FREETEXT(*,'FORMSOF(INFLECTIONAL, "stack", "overflow")');
```

Comment: Terence would you mind explaining how your second answer works? I got it working, but I would like to avoid inserting both keywords and just "stack overflow".

Comment: My fault, the inflectional part works like this... for input "ride" you'll get: riding, ridden, and so on. I will edit and correct the answer. You only need to give as input "stack" and "overflow". It seems also that FORMSOF works with FREETEXT, CONTAINS makes specific word matches whereas FREETEXT makes loosely matches.